# Teams webhook post (proxy authentication) failed

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to post a new Teams message. If I don't use proxy, pogram fails half start count with fail: `Proxy auth required`. If i try to use proxy, build fail by timeout (`post timeout`).

Maybe some fail in proxy settings?

```
using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{                    
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    UseProxy = true,
    Proxy = new WebProxy { UseDefaultCredentials = true }
})
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(HookUri, StringContent);
     }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Teams issue at all, rather something on your environment, if it requires Proxy details. Do you -have- a proxy server between you and the internet? If so, you might need to enter it's address.

Comment: @Artem, Hilton is right this isn't teams issue at all. Please check the proxy settings from your IT admin.

Comment: Adding BaseUri: "https://outlook.office.com/" helps to solve this problem